# Font icons twitching on hover

Tags: css, icons

I have an issue that is occurring in Chrome in a theme I created, when I hover over an image the font icons on the page are moving around. I've looked around for a solution but I can't find anyone mentioning this. Take a look at the [demo here](http://www.bluth.is/wordpress/keilir/) and hover your mouse over the image in the **second blog** post.

This is the css rule for the hover event:

```
.entry-image a:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.06);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.06);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.06);
  -o-transform: scale(1.06);
  transform: scale(1.06);
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Ivar Rafn

Comment: Have also had this issue a number of times based on :hover triggering flickers/movement in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

I just had to add a css rule for the :before pseudo-element to have margin:0 and display:inline and that took care of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you had a margin or position set with `ems` or `rems`. When an em or rem size resolves to a pixel value with decimal points (e.g., 17.100295px), hovers on nearby elements in Webkit and Blink can cause a little twitch.